# File processing-Haskell

Tags: haskell, file-processing, winghci

How can I implement in haskell the following:

1. I receive an input file from the command line. This input file contains words separated with tabs, new-lines and spaces.
2. I have to replace these elements (tabs, new-lines and spaces) with commas.
3. And then write the result to a file called `output.txt`.

Any help is much appreciated. My haskell skills still developing.

---

So far I've got this code:

```
    processFile::String->String
    processFile [] =[]
    processFile input =input

    process :: String -> IO String
    process fileName = do
    text <- readFile fileName
    return (processFile text)

    main :: IO ()
    main = do
    n <- process "input.txt"
    print n
```

In processFile function I should process the text from the input file.

Comment: Is this homework? What have you tried?

Comment: yes it's homework.I haven't tried much,as I don't have many ideas in haskell implementing.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `getArgs` function to read arguments on the command line. For example:

```
import System.Environment (getArgs)

main = do
  args <- getArgs
  case args of
    [arg] -> putStrLn $ "You gave me one arg: " ++ arg
    _     -> putStrLn $ "You gave me " ++ show (length args) ++ " arguments."
```

---

You can use the `readFile` function to read a file.

```
contents <- readFile "test.txt"
putStrLn contents -- Prints the contents of the file
```

---

You can use the `writeFile` function to write a file:

```
writeFile "test2.txt" "Some file data\n" -- Writes the data to the file
```

---

Tabs, newlines and spaces can be called whitespace, or word separators. The `words` function converts a string into a list of words.

```
print $ words "some text with\nmany words"
-- prints ["some", "text", "with", "many", "words"]
```

---

The `intersperse` function inserts a separator between each element of a list:

```
import Data.List (intersperse)

main =
  print $ intersperse '.' ["some", "text", "with", "many", "words"]
  -- prints "some.text.with.many.words"
```

You can also look at the `intercalate` function if you need longer separators.

---

These are all of the tools that you need for your program, I think that you can figure out the rest. Good luck!